# Use of "conocer" in the context of meeting someone

Tags: verbos, ambigüedad

From searching the web via Google, I'm finding that "conocer" can be used to express that one is meeting someone else *for the first time*.

Does this mean that two or more persons are meeting for the first time *ever*? Or does it mean for the first time within a particular day?

> No conoció a su madre.
>
> He didn't meet his mother.

The above Spanish is from a lesson I'm taking at Memrise.com. This confuses me because usually an individual is NOT meeting his mother for the first time ever. Why is it appropriate to use "conocer" in this context?

UPDATE: Perhaps I've made a faulty assumption here. In the example that I used, I assumed that 'his' is referring to the mother of 'he'. Perhaps 'his' is referring to someone else's mother. For example:

> He (Roberto) did not meet his (Brian's) mother.

In this case, this meeting that did not occur would have been a first-time meeting.

I hope that I'm making sense here! :)

Comment: Which word would you suggest instead of *conocer*?

Comment: @Ustanak: Spanishdict.com reveals that "encontrarse con" also means "to meet". Further research reveals it specifically means to meet someone that you already know, not meeting someone for the first time. It seems to me that "encontrarse con" is more appropriate when one wants to express that he or she is meeting his or her mother.

Comment: Not quite. Here's a far-fetched case: you have a friend X who has another friend Y. You know X because you knew him/her some time before you never spoke to Y. (So there's no *first time* with that person. Eye contact doesn't mean you actually know Y.) One day when walking you met Y (but you never spoke with him/her nor shared something together before) and you tell X the following: *me encontré con Y, salimos a beber*. This doesn't imply that you met Y before, because it's your first time sharing with Y.

Comment: Hahaa, I had to meditate on your response for a bit. Spanish seems to distinguish between 'meeting someone' and 'meeting some for the first time'. Ultimately, I'm trying to understand the proper usage for each case.

Comment: "El no conoció a su madre" could mean either he never met his mother (perhaps he was adopted, or otherwise separated from her at an early age), or, as your update indicates, it could mean that the "su" is referring to someone else's mother. The fuller context would be necessary to disambiguate.

Comment: @aparente por favor, no uses [meaning-in-context]. [Se debatió largo y tendido en Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2957/1674) y se decidió no usar, así que tenlo en cuenta. No es agradable tener que estar _vigilante_, pero menos aún lo es ver que lo que debatimos entre todos no se adopta. Usamos Meta para ir estableciendo reglas: seamos consecuentes con ellas.

Comment: @fedorqui - Okay.  I suggest you put a "status resolved" (sorry, I'm not remembering the precise tag right now) on that question.  I had not noticed that a decision had been made on that one.  (Would have been helpful to ping me there, since I was the one who created the tag.)  Anyway, now I know, and I will do my best to remember to leave it dead an buried.  (By the way, I don't mind -- it was just an experiment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Conocer*, in Spanish, has multiple meanings, just like *know* has multiple meanings in English.

RAE lists [10 usages of *conocer*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AMmujSR). The most relevant ones to your question are:

> - tr. Entender, advertir, saber, echar de ver a alguien o algo.
> - tr. Tener trato y comunicación con alguien. U. t. c. prnl.

Roughly translated:

> - transitive verb. Understand, notice, know, or to see someone or something.
> - transitive verb. Engage in dealings and communication with someone.

So the explanation is simply that the word has multiple meanings.  It can mean to know someone, and it can mean to meet someone.

Some examples of how to use conocer, and how to talk about meeting and meeting up:

> - ¿Conoces a Maria?  / *Do you know Maria?*
> - ¿Conociste a Maria? / *Did you meet Maria (for the first time)?*
> - Ayer conocí a tu jefe. / *Yesterday I met your boss (for the first time).*
> - Vamos a juntarnos en el café. / *We will met up in the café.*
> - Encontré a Maria en el supermercado. / *I met/ran into/found Maria in the supermarket.*
> - ¿Conoces Ámsterdam? / *Do you know/are you familiar with/have you been to Amsterdam?*

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy. I guess I'm hoping for a fluent speaker to reply how he or she uses 'conocer' in normal everyday speech (in the context of meeting people).

Comment: I've added some examples. Let me know if further clarification is useful.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, things are so much clearer now. Also, I've updated my original post after having an epiphany.

Answer (score 3):

As a native Spanish speaker, the use of this verb often depends of context.

We can use *conocer* when the person introduced already knows the other.

> — Hola, este es Paul.
>   — Hola, ya lo **conozco**.

When you want to meet someone or more people for the first time:

> — Quiero **conocer** más amigos.

When talking about knowledge:

> — **Conocer** estas materias, ampliará tu mente.

However, we don't use *conocer* when we casually meet people:

> — Ayer me **encontré** a Paul en el mercado. ( <s>Ayer **conocí** a Paul en el Mercado.</s>)

Comment: Thanks. You've further confirmed that 'conocer' is not used when meeting someone after the first time. I see that 'encontrar' can be used for that.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson We can also use *me topé con alguien.*

Answer (score 1):

"Conocer," in this context, is to meet for the first time *ever.*

A rough English translation is, "get to know."

Before you "conocer" this person, you don't know him/her *at all.*

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question in your update.  That is exactly right.  The "he" and the "his" refer, most likely, to two different people.  The authors of your textbook should have constructed a better sentence to avoid confusion.

Also, in the past tense, negative, it would be unlikely to use this verb in such a sentence.  It would be more likely to find

> Roberto no conocía a la mamá de Brian. *(Roberto wasn't acquainted with Brian's mother.)*

or

> Roberto no se encontró con la mamá de Brian. *(Roberto didn't meet up with Brian's mother.)*